# Printing an array of integers in a collection of buttons, Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I am creating a quiz game in Xcode and I have a screen after the quiz is complete that shows the 5 questions asked (from an array of 70+) with the corresponding correct answer (Answer) and the answer the user selected (UserAnswer).

I currently have a collection of labels for correct answers (CorrectAnswer) and a separate collection of labels for user answers YourAnswer. I want to consecutively print all 5 values stored for each of the arrays in each of the collections of 5 labels (QuestionName, YourAnswer, CorrectAnswer).

Im new to coding in general so any help with using arrays in loops be appreciated.

First View Controller:

```
struct Question {
   var Question : String
   var Answers : [String]!
   var Answer : Int!
   var UserAnswer : Int!
   }

var Questions = [Question]()
```

Second View Controller:

```
class ScoreViewController: UIViewController {

var Questions = [Question]()
var CorrectAnswerTotal = Int()
var QuestionNumberTotal = Int()
let TOTAL_QUESTIONS = 0
var AnswerNumber = Int()


@IBOutlet var QuestionName: [UILabel]!
@IBOutlet var YourAnswer: [UILabel]!
@IBOutlet var CorrectAnswer: [UILabel]!


  for i in 0..<Questions.count {

    var q = Questions[i].Question
    var ai = Questions[i].Answer
    var a = Questions[i].Answers[ai]
    var uai = Questions[i].UserAnswer
    var ua = Questions[i].Answers[uai]

     //This is where the error is

    if QuestionNumberTotal < TOTAL_QUESTIONS {

            if (ai != uai){

                QuestionName.text = Questions[i].Question
                YourAnswer.text = Questions[i].UserAnswer
                CorrectAnswer.text = Questions[i].Answer

               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to ask if there's something unclear.

```
struct Question {
    var question: String
    var answers: [String]
    var correctAnswer: Int
    var userAnswer: Int
}

var questions = [Question]()
var correctAnswerTotal = 0

@IBOutlet var questionName: [UILabel]!
@IBOutlet var yourAnswer: [UILabel]!
@IBOutlet var correctAnswer: [UILabel]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // fill it with some examples
    questions.append(Question(question: "Question 1?", answers: ["Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "4", "Answer 5"], correctAnswer: 0, userAnswer: 1))
    questions.append(Question(question: "Question 2?", answers: ["Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "4", "Answer 5"], correctAnswer: 1, userAnswer: 2))
    questions.append(Question(question: "Question 3?", answers: ["Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "4", "Answer 5"], correctAnswer: 3, userAnswer: 3))

    // assure, that the necessary amount of labels exists
    guard questionName.count >= questions.count
        && yourAnswer.count >= questions.count
        && correctAnswer.count >= questions.count else {
        print("Not enough labels.")
        return
    }

    // starts at 0 and ends at last-1
    for i in 0..<questions.count {

        let q = questions[i]
        let user = q.answers[q.userAnswer]
        let correct = q.answers[q.correctAnswer]

        // set labels texts
        questionName[i].text = q.question
        yourAnswer[i].text = user
        correctAnswer[i].text = correct

        // correct answer is green, incorrect answer is red
        if q.correctAnswer == q.userAnswer {
            correctAnswerTotal += 1
            yourAnswer[i].textColor = UIColor.green
        } else {
            yourAnswer[i].textColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful however it does not all work as my labels are outlet collections not just single outlets.